# How to remove extra commas when retrieving data from mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some data stored in a mysql table and the output has some additional commas which I don't need.

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT REMOTE_INT FROM R3")
2L
>>> x = cursor.fetchall()
>>> x
((u'xe-0/0/0',), (u'xe-0/0/1',))
>>> x[0]
(u'xe-0/0/0',)
>>> x[1]
(u'xe-0/0/1',)
>>>
```

Also any suggestions on removing the 'u'? I want to be able to use these values of x in other parts of the script.

Comment: The commas are not 'extra commas' - they're indications that the object you're getting back is a tuple (or tuple of tuples in this case) and your result is the first item in the tuple. The `u` indicates the data is a unicode string; it won't stop you from using the data anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand its a tuple but i wasnt sure how to use the value in my script because of the additional commas. But i think i have the answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [fetchall documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set
>   and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it
>   returns an empty list.

I am not a big fan of fetchall and would like to suggest that you use [fetchone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) or use the cursor as an iterator. however all of these methods still return a tuple.

You can convert the tuple returned to you into a simple list by doing

```
[ x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

This effectively 'removes the extra comma'

Comment: Done! Thanks for the tip!